# How do I prove that $f(x) = ln(x) − (x − 4)^2$ has exactly two roots.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I assume we take the derivative of the function.
I get: $y' = 1/x-2(x-4)$ and I attempt to set it to 0 and solve but get stuck. Any tips?

Comment: The main theorem of algebra states that every n-th degree polynomial has exactly n complex roots. I am confused about the problem.

Comment: @AlvinLepik I am confused about how polynomials are involved in this problem.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $2x^2-8x-1=0$. This has exactly one positive root.

Answer (score 4):

Outline: 1) $f(1)\lt 0$, $f(4)\gt 0$, $f(10)\lt 0$, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem $f(x)=0$ has at least two roots. 2) By the Mean Value Theorem, between any two roots of $f(x)=0$ there is at least one root of $f'(x)=0$. 3) The equation $f'(x)=0$ has exactly one positive root.

Answer (score 2):

From 
$$
\frac1x=2x-8,
$$
you multiply both sides by $x$ to get 
$$
1=2x^2-8x,
$$
of $x^2-8x-1$. Since $x^2-8x-1=(x-4)^2-17$, its roots are $4\pm\sqrt{17}$. But our function only exists for $x>0$, and so in its domain the derivative has a single root.

Now, 
$$
f(1)=-9,\ \ f(4)=\log4>0. 
$$
This guarantees a root for $f$ in $(0,4)$. We also have that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, so eventually $f$ has to be negative again, so it crosses the $x$ axis again: a second root. And there cannot be another one, because to "climb up" again and cross the $x$ axis one more time, the derivative would be zero at a second point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The roots are given by 
$$
\log x=(x-4)^2
$$

when we have so simple functions the first approach is to plot a graph, as in the figure, where we represents the two functions. 
Tis is simple because you know (I suppose) the graph of $y=\log x$ and the graph of $y=(x-4)^2$ is a positive parabola with vertex at $(4,0)$.(see the figure).

And this gives you a first intuition of the possible solutions that are the abscissa of the intersection points of the two graphs.  Not a proof, but than you can refine, if you want, with more analytical considerations as in the other answers.

[image]